# How to copy the first Unselected element from a listBox to another in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need code that helps me to copy the first Unselected element from a listBox to another, I already know how to copy all unselected elements as below but I need to copy just the first Elemnet from the lisbox:

```
                For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox3.Items.Count - 1
                    If ListBox3.GetSelected(i) Then
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox3.Items(i))
                    Else
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(ListBox3.Items(i))
                    End If
                Next
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method.
It'll copy all the unselected, but easy to modify to just copy the first found.

```
Private Sub CopyUnselectedButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyUnselectedButton.Click

    For iterator As Integer = 0 To SourceListBox.Items.Count - 1

        Dim item As Object = SourceListBox.Items(iterator)

        If Not SourceListBox.SelectedItems.Contains(item) Then
            DestListBox.Items.Add(SourceListBox.Items(iterator))
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the modification, I tried but I failed.

Comment: Updated with an exit after the first found.

Comment: It's working, appractited your kind help